# C# Assertについて

Tags: c#

どちらでも良いというような見解しか得られなかったため、質問させていただきます。
C#でテストを行うとき、MicrosoftのUnitTestingにあるAssertとNUnitにあるAssertではどちらを選べばよいのでしょうか？
具体的な違い、また使用するメリットをご享受下さい。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

はっきりって機能面ではどちらでも良いです。ですが環境面で言うと対応しているバージョン等にいろいろと差異があります。

## Microsoft単体テスト

- Visual StudioのExpress版では使用できません
- IDEのサポートは比較的古いバージョンでも対応しています

## NUnit

- 実行ファイルをNuGet等で入手する必要があります
- 単体アプリケーションとしては.NET 1.1以降の全環境で使用できます
- IDE上でのテスト実行にはVSの拡張機能(NUnit Test Adapter)が必要です
- Test Adapterのサポートは2012以降で、MS単体テストに比べると若干デバッグ動作に問題があります

個人的にはプロジェクト関係者(特に受け入れテスト担当者)がVS Pro/Communityを入手可能な状況ならMS単体テストを、そうでなければNUnitを選択するのがよいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

質問から外れてしまいますが、
xUnitというものも有ります。MSUnitよりはNUnitに近いですね。
Microsoftが作っているオープンソースのテストフレームワークはほぼxUnitです。
海外でもNUnit vs xUnitでxUnitが推されることが多いようです。
ご参考まで。